# Не могу загрузить сессию в linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cinnamon

Решил обновить Ubuntu с 14 до 16 LTS. Во время установки обновлений завис компьютер и перезагрузился. Слетела графическая оболочка и я решил снести ее через purge и установить cinnamon. dpg попросил востановить загрузку и я ему позволил.

Сейчас при вводе пароля меня просто выбивает на туже страницу. Если в консоле ввести **startx** cinnamon запускается.

Как исправить? Место на hdd достаточно xorg и xserver переустанавливал.

**lsb_release -a**

```
    No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: я в этом случае ставлю с ноля. важные файлы бекапь с лайф-сд. за эти 3 рабочих дня побил свой рекорд по установке убунту на железо - 56 раз, использую preseed файл один раз настроть потом все на автомате.  про апгрейд убунту - очень шаткая у них эта модель 30 к 70 что все пройдет успешно. если только Х полетели C-M-F5 скинет тебя в консоль без Х, снеси битый X. поставь с ноля cinanon и не забудь про логин сервер в в убунту xdm. в 16 убунту wayland а не xorg.

Comment: Решил не морочить себе голову и установить старый добрый Debian. В очередной раз разочаровался в Ubuntu с его Unity